# Number of list of increasing n-tuples

Tags: combinatorics

Let $l=(t_i)_{i\leq k}$ be a list of tuple such that :

- $t_0=(0,...,0)$
- $\forall i\leq k-1$, $\exists 1\leq j\leq n$ such that $t_{i+1}[j]=t_i[j]+1$
- $\forall m\neq j$, $t_i[m]=t_{i+1}[m]$

In other words, $l$ is a list of $n$ tuples such that only one position increase by one at each step.

I want to know the number of such list given $n$ (the size of the tuple) and $l$ (the largest element in the tuples). Actually I just need a big O of this number.

The better bound I found is $(l^n)^{(l*n)}$ but it does not take in account the structure of the lists (single increment).

I'm am sure we can do better but failed to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your largest element be $t_k=(l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n)$ with $k=\sum_{i=1}^n l_i$. Your problem is stated with $l_1=l_2=\ldots=l$, but this generalization isn't any more difficult.

Your list can be uniquely described by stating, for each element $t_i, i \le k-1$ which index will have the value exactly 1 less when compared to $t_{i+1}$ (aka: what value has $j$ in your second bullet point).

Since at each index $i$, the value goes from $0$ in $t_0$ to $l_i$ in $t_k$, the index $i$ will be chosen exactly $l_i$ times. Conversely, if you are given a list of $k$ indexes and index $i$ occurs exactly $l_i$ times, this can be turned back into a list of tuples that starts with $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ and ends with $t_k$. Your list of tuples and the list of indices are in a direct 1-to-1 correspondence.

Counting the number of those index lists is easy. You have k elements to bring into a list (order them), but not all of them are different (there are $l_1$ indices of $1$, a.s.o.) That would be permutations with repetition in my terminology, which Wikipedia calls Permutations with Multisets

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets

The formula would be

$$\text{#lists} = \frac{k!}{l_1!\cdot l_2!\cdot \ldots l_n!}$$

In your case we have $k=nl$, $l_1=l_2=\cdots l$ and thus

$$\text{#lists} = \frac{(nl)!}{l!^n}$$

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do something with the index, but get lost because of the repetition. Permutation with repetition (multi sets) are exactly what I need. Thanks again.